# Interpreting F# files with Mono

Tags: macos, f#, interpreter

After installing F# on OS X with Homebrew, In Haskell (with GHC), it's possible run code on an interpreter. I was wondering if there is a way to run files without compiling them first in F#? Maybe with fsharpi?

Just to clarify, I do not mean the REPL itself, but running an app without intermediary files.

Comment: fsharpi can run fsx files which are no different really to .fs files except for an extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fsharpi` which is an interactive mode for F#. You can just start `fsharpi` and then type F# code in the console that starts:

```
> 1 + 1;;
val it : int = 2
```

You can also write your code in a `fsx` file and pass it to `fsharpi` to have it executed. Say you have `demo.fsx` with:

```
printfn "Hello world"
```

You can then run `fsharpi demo.fsx` and it should print hello world for you!

Some people use F# from command line in this way, but it gets more productive if you setup your favorite editor to use F# - then you can type code directly in the editor and send it to F# Interactive using some command. There are good plugins for [Atom](https://github.com/ionide/ionide-fsharp), Emacs, vim, Sublime and others - [see the links here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/blob/master/README.md).

PS: It is worth adding that F# Interactive does not actually interpret the code. It compiles it on the fly and runs it, so it has the same performance profile as compiling the code in the usual way.

Comment: AFAIK, technically, GHC also doesn't interpret. I think OP meant REPL.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin In GHC, using `runghc` is what I believe is an interpreter (I may be wrong about that), `ghci` is a REPL, and `ghc` is the compiler. `fsharpi *.fsx` looks like what I've been searching for.